# How to recreate the Oppenheimer "atom vibration" FX?

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, effects

I'm planning to make a small movie soon and I would like to recreate the kind of effect found in Oppenheimer (2023) with the vibrating atom ([see this video for a demonstration](https://youtu.be/RiHhQ8zc-UU?si=s7A7MMNmd65oIWrX&t=75)
).
Is there a way in Blender to recreate this effect pretty easily? I would assume that using Geometry nodes there could be a way to recreate this effect, however I do not have any idea how these works.
Or maybe using curves and doing some camera and post-process work? I'm pretty stuck on how I could imagine such a set-up in Blender.
Honestly, I have thought about ways but did not do any tests inside Blender as I'm pretty sure my knowledge for this kind of work (FX) is limited.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: **Note:** I've open a new post on [Blender's subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/18qp538/how_to_recreate_the_oppenheimer_atom_vibration_fx/). No need to send me there to find the answer!

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I'm really sorry, I was a bit in a hurry when I made this post. Should have waited to have more time on my hand, and I didn't know you could post GIFs here. Definitely going to keep your advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a circle with concentric edges, unwrap and orthogonalize with the UV Squares addon, give it a material that will be a mix between emissive and transparent waves and a gradient that will make it transparent at its periphery and center:

[image]

Keyframe the *Wave Texture* scale value, the *ColorRamp* node, keyframe the rotation of the object and put a *Noise* modifier to make it shake, etc...:

[image]

Comment: Incredible! Thank you very much. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: With a stretched noise there is a noticeable seam in the texture then which is not shown in the screenshot... or did you get rid of it somehow? Because I do not know how...

Comment: Oh yes I missed that, of course   ;)